# Django: Simplifying long 'join's?

Tags: django, django-orm

I've got a few long queries (for checking capabilities) which look like this:

```
widgets = Widget.objects.filter(
    Q(owner__memberships = current_user),
    Q(owner__memberships__memberships__capabilities__name = "widget_list")
)
```

Is there any reasonable way of simplifying that query? Or do I just need to live with it?

The relevant models are:

```
class Widget(m.Model):
    owner = m.ForeignKey(Group)

class Group(m.Model):
    memberships = m.ManyToManyField(User, through=GroupMembership)

class GroupMembership(m.Model):
    user = m.ForeignKey(User)
    group = m.ForeignKey(Group)
    capabilities = m.ManyToMany(Capability)

class Capability(m.Model):
    name = m.CharField(...)
```

Comment: On the positive side, at least one doesn't have to write out the full JOIN in SQL directly.

Comment: In this case, I'm actually feeling like it would be easier to write them out… :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap your parameters in Q() objects, you can use the key/value pairs directly:

```
widgets = Widget.objects.filter(
    owner__memberships = current_user,
    owner__memberships__memberships__capabilities__name = "widget_list"
)
```

Comment: Hrm, although it's actually looking like this doesn't do what I want. ie, it's querying for all Widgets where the `current_user` is a member of the owning group and the `current_user` has the `"widget_list"` capability in *some* group…